# Bug in review queue?

Tags: bug, review

When I click on the review queue, often there are items in two categories to review. When I finish one queue, however, and click on "view all review queues", the list then comes up empty for all queues. It doesn't matter which queues they are, or what I click on to return to the queues.

At first I thought there was someone else checking the queue at the same time. Now I doubt that's what's happening.

It doesn't happen on any other sites I'm active on.

Is this a bug? Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it primarily happens when you review posts that are contained in multiple queues.  For example, a new user makes a very low quality first post.  Our site is low volume enough for that effect to be significant.

Comment: Hmm. That makes perfect sense. Thanks!